S3FileLoader doesn't support password file
S3FileLoader(bucket=self.aws_bucket,key=payload["filePath"],
                mode="paged",
                region_name=self.region_name,
                aws_access_key_id=self.aws_access_key_id,
                aws_secret_access_key=self.aws_secret_access_key,
                unstructured_kwargs={"password": "test"},
            )
docs = loader.load()


Unable to get a page count.
Command Line Error: Incorrect password

I am getting this error when I pass the password
